# Converting SQL to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having troubles converting the following SQL query to an ActiveRecord query.
This would be the query in raw SQL:

```
SELECT customers.name, customers.email, customers.address, (sales.quantity * sales.price AS total_spent)
FROM customers JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.id
ORDER BY total_spent DESC
```

I've done this to start working on that for ordering the top customers but it doesn't work:

```
Customer.joins(:buys).group("customers.id").select("id", "name", "price"*"stock" as "total_buys")
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up your model associations and add some convenience methods

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales

  # if you add a subtotal field that is autocalculated you could also do this
  def total_spent
    self.sales.all.map(|sale| sale.total ).sum 
  end
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def total
    self.price * self.amount
  end
end
```

Then in your app or the console you can type:

```
Customer.first.sales.map(&:total).sum
```

Or all Customers:

```
Customer.all.each{ |c| puts c.sales.map(&:total).sum }
```

Comment: Thanks that will work. But I want to do it as a query operation. I don't want to implement Ruby code when a query will be more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I thought you said you wanted to convert it to an AR query. I doubt it will add much overhead.